# php FILTER_CALLBACK with closure

Tags: php, filter

Trying to pass a closure into filter_var_array(), but can't seem to make it work.

```
$clean = function( $html ) {
    return HTML::sanitize( $html, array('p','ul','ol','li'), array('class','style') );
};
$args = array( 'filter' => FILTER_CALLBACK, 'options' => $clean );

$fields = filter_var_array(
    array( $_POST['field1'], $_POST['field2'], $_POST['field3'] ),
    array( 'field1' => $args, 'field2' => $args, 'field3' => $args )
);
```

After the above is run, $fields is an empty array.

Note, individual filtering works fine:

```
$field1= filter_var( $_POST['field1'], FILTER_CALLBACK, array( 'options' => $clean ) );
```

Any ideas?

Comment: *(sidenote)* you can pass in `$_POST` directly instead of wrapping fields from it in a new array

Comment: @Gordon: Actually that is causing the problem.

Comment: I highly suggest you review the samples given in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var-array.php - should make the usage more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing in the values of `$_POST` without their keys, hence no callbacks will be triggered. Just pass in the entire `$_POST` array instead, e.g.

```
$fields = filter_var_array(
    $_POST,
    array(
        'field1' => $args, 
        'field2' => $args, 
        'field3' => $args 
    )
);
```

Comment: Ha, I knew I had to be making some bonehead error. Thanks everyone. I should of stepped away from the code for a couple of minutes before posting.

Answer (score 2):

`filter_var_array` expects An array with string keys containing the data to filter and An array defining the arguments. A valid key is a string containing a variable name and a valid value is either a filter type, or an array optionally specifying the filter, flags and options.

Your implementation should be like this :

```
$clean = function ($html) {
    return HTML::sanitize($html, array('p','ul','ol','li'), array('class','style'));
};

$filter = array('filter' => FILTER_CALLBACK,'options' => $clean);
$args = array("field1" => $filter,"field2" => $filter,"field3" => $filter);
$fields = filter_var_array($_POST, $args);
```